# PostgresSQL PITR

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a master\server setup with pgpool and postgres 9.5. Both servers are running on centOS7.

I wanted to setup a point in time recovery with base backups every saturday, eliminating the old xlogs.

The server is archiving the xlogs with success  on a external filesystem.

But when i try to execute the basebackup command it gives the following error:

> pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "replication" does not exist.

I can't find any solution.

I would be grateful for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: You may want to post the actual command you're running, and the name of your database, as well as any relevant configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using `psql` with a user named `replication`, or you're using a program that calls `psql`

If you don't specify the database name, `psql` tries to connect to a database with the same name as the username

Try setting the PGDATABASE environment variable:

```
$ PGDATABASE=foo psql
```

or

```
$ export PGDATABASE=foo
$ ./some-program-that-calls-psql
```